# Tracing/profiling instructions

Tags: c, assembly, profiling, instructions

I'd like to statistically profile my C code at the instruction level.
I need to know how many additions, multiplications, divisions, etc I'm performing.

This is not your usual run of the mill code profiling requirement. I'm an algorithm developer and I want to estimate the cost of converting my code to hardware implementations. For this, I'm being asked the instruction call breakdown during run-time (parsing the compiled assembly isn't sufficient as it doesn't consider loops in the code).

After looking around, it seems VMware may offer a possible solution, but I still couldn't find the specific feature that will allow me to trace the instruction call stream of my process.

Are you aware of any profiling tools which enable this?

Comment: Seems to me you want to look not only at execution counts of such instructions, but at the overall fraction of time they account for because, for example, suppose they take 50% of the time, and you can reduce that part to negligible, you've only gotten a factor of 2 speedup.

Comment: Execution time is not important in this specific case.
I'm not profiling for code optimization.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I eventually used a trivial yet effective solution.

1. Configured GDB to display the disassembly of the next instruction (every time it stops) by invoking:

`display/i $pc`

2. Configured a simple gdb script that breaks in the function I need to analyze and proceeds to step instruction by instruction:
   `set $i=0
   break main
   run
   while ($i<100000)
   si
   set $i = $i + 1
   end
   quit`
3. Executed gdb with my script dumping output into a log file:

   `gdb -x script a.out > log.txt`
4. Analyzed the log to count specific instruction calls.

Crude, but it works...

Answer (score 6):

You can use [pin-instat](https://github.com/wuyongzheng/pin-instat) which is a PIN tool. It's a bit over kill as it records more information than the instruction count. It still should be more efficient than your gdb approach through.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of pin-instat.

Comment: As a computer architect, this little piece of software really helps me reason about my designs, Thank you for doing this work!

Comment: It is possible to attach pin-instat to an existing process?

Comment: @Sush Yes. `PINDIR/pin.sh -t obj-intel64/instat.so -p <pid>`

Answer (score 6):

The Linux tool `perf` will give you a good deal of profiling information; specifically, [`perf annotate`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Source_level_analysis_with_perf_annotate) will give you per-instruction relative counts.

> It is possible to drill down to the instruction level with `perf annotate`. For that, you need to invoke `perf annotate` with the name of the command to annotate. All the functions with samples will be disassembled and each instruction will have its relative percentage of samples reported:
>
> ```
> perf record ./noploop 5
> perf annotate -d ./noploop
>
> ------------------------------------------------
>  Percent |   Source code & Disassembly of noploop.noggdb
> ------------------------------------------------
>          :
>          :
>          :
>          :   Disassembly of section .text:
>          :
>          :   08048484 <main>:
>     0.00 :    8048484:       55                      push   %ebp
>     0.00 :    8048485:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp [...]
>     0.00 :    8048530:       eb 0b                   jmp    804853d <main+0xb9>
>    15.08 :    8048532:       8b 44 24 2c             mov    0x2c(%esp),%eax
>     0.00 :    8048536:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
>    14.52 :    8048539:       89 44 24 2c             mov    %eax,0x2c(%esp)
>    14.27 :    804853d:       8b 44 24 2c             mov    0x2c(%esp),%eax
>    56.13 :    8048541:       3d ff e0 f5 05          cmp    $0x5f5e0ff,%eax
>     0.00 :    8048546:       76 ea                   jbe    8048532 <main+0xae> [...]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The valgrind tool [cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) can be used to get execution counts of each line in the compiled assembly (the `Ir` value in the first column).

Answer (score 2):

**QEMU user mode `-d in_asm`**

Edit: `-d in_asm` alone shows only translation chunks, so if a chunk gets executed multiple times, it won't show multiple times. There are some extra flags that make it more accurate, see: [What instructions does qemu trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847254/what-instructions-does-qemu-trace/64876198#64876198) QEMU's `exec_tb` trace backend might however do it: [How to use QEMU's simple trace backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149446/how-to-use-qemus-simple-trace-backend/46497873#46497873)

This is another simple thing you can do to get an instruction trace:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-user
qemu-x86_64 -d in_asm main.out
```

Let's test it with an x86_64 triple hello world:

main.S

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
asm_main_after_prologue:
    mov $3, %rbx
write:
    mov $1, %rax    /* syscall number */
    mov $1, %rdi    /* stdout */
    mov $msg, %rsi  /* buffer */
    mov $len, %rdx  /* len */
    syscall
    dec %rbx
    jne write
exit:
    mov $60, %rax   /* syscall number */
    mov $0, %rdi    /* exit status */
    syscall
msg:
    .ascii "hello\n"
len = . - msg
```

adapted from [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/d9f70405a7253ad43b649f4b6d7ab2215b10645e/userland/arch/x86_64/freestanding/linux/hello.S).

Assemble and run with:

```
as -o main.o main.S 
ld -o main.out main.o
./main.out
```

Stdout output:

```
hello
hello
hello
```

Running it through QEMU outputs the instruction trace to stderr:

```
warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
host mmap_min_addr=0x10000
Reserved 0x1000 bytes of guest address space
Relocating guest address space from 0x0000000000400000 to 0x400000
guest_base  0x0
start            end              size             prot
0000000000400000-0000000000401000 0000000000001000 r-x
0000004000000000-0000004000001000 0000000000001000 ---
0000004000001000-0000004000801000 0000000000800000 rw-
start_brk   0x0000000000000000
end_code    0x00000000004000b8
start_code  0x0000000000400000
start_data  0x00000000004000b8
end_data    0x00000000004000b8
start_stack 0x00000040007fed70
brk         0x00000000004000b8
entry       0x0000000000400078
----------------
IN: 
0x0000000000400078:  mov    $0x3,%rbx
0x000000000040007f:  mov    $0x1,%rax
0x0000000000400086:  mov    $0x1,%rdi
0x000000000040008d:  mov    $0x4000b2,%rsi
0x0000000000400094:  mov    $0x6,%rdx
0x000000000040009b:  syscall 

----------------
IN: 
0x000000000040009d:  dec    %rbx
0x00000000004000a0:  jne    0x40007f

----------------
IN: 
0x000000000040007f:  mov    $0x1,%rax
0x0000000000400086:  mov    $0x1,%rdi
0x000000000040008d:  mov    $0x4000b2,%rsi
0x0000000000400094:  mov    $0x6,%rdx
0x000000000040009b:  syscall 

----------------
IN: 
0x00000000004000a2:  mov    $0x3c,%rax
0x00000000004000a9:  mov    $0x0,%rdi
0x00000000004000b0:  syscall
```

I expect this method to be relatively fast. It works by reading input instructions and producing output instructions that the host can run, much like cachegrind which was mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2971979/895245

One cool thing about this is that you can also trivially trace executables of other architectures, see for example aarch64: [How does native android code written for ARM run on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005303/how-does-native-android-code-written-for-arm-run-on-x86/44505097#44505097)

This method also displays the current symbol of unstripped executables, e.g. the trace of:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int say_hello() {
    puts("hello");
}

int main(void) {
    say_hello();
}
```

compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -o main.out main.c
qemu-x86_64 -d in_asm ./main.out
```

contains:

```
----------------
IN: main
0x0000000000400537:  push   %rbp
0x0000000000400538:  mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040053b:  mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400540:  callq  0x400526

----------------
IN: say_hello
0x0000000000400526:  push   %rbp
0x0000000000400527:  mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040052a:  mov    $0x4005d4,%edi
0x000000000040052f:  callq  0x400400

----------------
IN: 
0x0000000000400400:  jmpq   *0x200c12(%rip)        # 0x601018
```

It does not however show symbols within shared libraries such as puts.

But you can see them if you compile with `-static`:

```
----------------
IN: main
0x00000000004009bf:  push   %rbp
0x00000000004009c0:  mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000004009c3:  mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004009c8:  callq  0x4009ae

----------------
IN: say_hello
0x00000000004009ae:  push   %rbp
0x00000000004009af:  mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000004009b2:  mov    $0x4a1064,%edi
0x00000000004009b7:  callq  0x40faa0

----------------
IN: puts
0x000000000040faa0:  push   %r12
0x000000000040faa2:  push   %rbp
0x000000000040faa3:  mov    %rdi,%r12
0x000000000040faa6:  push   %rbx
0x000000000040faa7:  callq  0x423830
```

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147343/how-to-determine-what-instructions-a-process-is-executing

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04, QEMU 2.5.0.