# How does native android code written for ARM run on x86?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, native, android-x86

Motorola just released an x86 based Android phone. I'm a little confused as to how native apps/libraries written for ARM(netflix for example) can run on this phone.

I'd be grateful if someone could explain.

Comment: Probably ARM native code cannot run on x86, or at least needs an emulator.

Comment: It can be achieved through *binary translation* or technologies alike at the runtime. ref:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation

Comment: And some more example with QEMU: QEMU also has a TCG accelerator, *which takes the guest assembly instructions and compiles it on the fly into comparable host instructions or calls to host helper routines; while not as fast as hardware acceleration, it allows cross-hardware emulation, such as **running ARM code on x86**.* ref: https://www.qemu.org/2018/02/09/understanding-qemu-devices/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, ARM native code runs on Intel x86 using an emulation feature named **Houdini**

What this library does is reads ARM instructions on the fly and converts them to equivalent x86 instructions. This is the reason why many apps may work as is on x86 without actually having to build an equivalent library.

[image]

Comment: I imagine that the type of application where developers have deliberately used the NDK are compute heavy and possibly real-time.  I don't imagine code translation is going to be great news.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do it the other way round? So x86 to ARM? so that Windows RT would work with x86 apps?
And is the performance hit huge?

Comment: This is only on Android. I don't know how windows is porting its apps to both arch's. Performance hit is pretty minimal. I haven't heard of complains about apps struggling on x86.

Comment: I have a new ASUS x86 quad core tablet and that thing runs ARM code as fast as my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 with benchmarks iv'e ran with C# Mono.  If you compile your code for x86 though, it runs 3 times as fast as ARM equivalent in GHz from my test.

Comment: I also installed the Android-x86 linux project on my old Intel Atom Netbook 1005HA and that thing runs twice as fast with Android vs Windows7 or GNU Linux.

Comment: @Yamcha Possible? Probably. But will it ever happen? I don't think so. As far as I know, AMD is the only company that Intel has authorized to use the x86 architecture. ARM on the other hand licenses to pretty much anyone including Intel. I think their whole business model is to just sell their IP cores; at least I've never heard of ARM manufacturing or selling chips.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work if you use an so/dll file in your APK

Answer (score 9):

You can actually include different native code for different architecture, not sure how Netflix is running but if you open apk you can see `/lib/armeabi-v7a/` , so I assume there  can be a folder something like `/lib/x86/`

Edit: I just checked Amazon shopping app it has native code for arm and x86. So maybe Thats how netflix does it too.

Comment: I think that directory root is `libs` not `lib`, still a nice answer

Answer (score 6):

**The Android Studio 3 emulator uses QEMU as a backend**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU

QEMU is arguably the leading open source cross arch emulator. It is GPL software, and supports many, many more archs in addition to x86 and ARM.

Android then just adds some bit of UI magic on top of QEMU and possibly some patches, but the core is definitely in QEMU upstream.

QEMU uses a technique called binary translation to achieve reasonably fast emulation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation

Binary translation basically translates ARM instructions into equivalent x86 instructions.

Therefore, to understand the details, the best way is to:

- read QEMU source code: https://github.com/qemu/qemu
- study binary translation in general, possibly write your own toy implementation

**Theory**

- CPUs are "[Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)" (up to memory limits)
- CPUs have a simple deterministic behavior that can be simulated with finite memory Turing machines

Therefore, it is clear that any CPU can emulate any CPU given enough memory.

The hard question is how to do that *fast*.

**Practice: QEMU user mode simulation**

QEMU has an userland mode that makes it very easy to play with userland ARM code on your x86 machine to see what is happening, as long as your guest and host are the same OS.

In this mode, what happens is that binary translation takes care of the basic instructions, and system calls are just forwarded to the host system calls.

E.g., for Linux on Linux with a Linux freestanding (no glibc) hello world:

main.S

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
asm_main_after_prologue:
    /* write */
    mov x0, 1
    adr x1, msg
    ldr x2, =len
    mov x8, 64
    svc 0

    /* exit */
    mov x0, 0
    mov x8, 93
    svc 0
msg:
    .ascii "hello syscall v8\n"
len = . - msg
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/1989bbdda7a57c077f4c63a1a271d5a43a384185/v8/linux/hello.S).

Then assemble and run as:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-user gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
aarch64-linux-gnu-as -o main.o main.S
aarch64-linux-gnu-ld -o main.out main.o
qemu-aarch64 main.out
```

and it outputs the expected:

```
hello syscall v8
```

You can even run ARM programs compiled against the C standard library, and GDB step debug the program! See this concrete example: [How to single step ARM assembly in GDB on QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590155/how-to-single-step-arm-assembly-in-gdb-on-qemu/51310791#51310791)

Since we are talking about binary translation, we can also enable some logging to see the exact translation that QEMU is doing:

```
qemu-aarch64 -d in_asm,out_asm main.out
```

Here:

- `in_asm` refers to the ARM guest input assembly
- `out_asm` refers to X86 host generated assembly that gets run

The output contains:

```
----------------
IN: 
0x0000000000400078:  d2800020      mov x0, #0x1
0x000000000040007c:  100000e1      adr x1, #+0x1c (addr 0x400098)
0x0000000000400080:  58000182      ldr x2, pc+48 (addr 0x4000b0)
0x0000000000400084:  d2800808      mov x8, #0x40
0x0000000000400088:  d4000001      svc #0x0

OUT: [size=105]
0x5578d016b428:  mov    -0x8(%r14),%ebp
0x5578d016b42c:  test   %ebp,%ebp
0x5578d016b42e:  jne    0x5578d016b482
0x5578d016b434:  mov    $0x1,%ebp
0x5578d016b439:  mov    %rbp,0x40(%r14)
0x5578d016b43d:  mov    $0x400098,%ebp
0x5578d016b442:  mov    %rbp,0x48(%r14)
0x5578d016b446:  mov    $0x4000b0,%ebp
0x5578d016b44b:  mov    0x0(%rbp),%rbp
0x5578d016b44f:  mov    %rbp,0x50(%r14)
0x5578d016b453:  mov    $0x40,%ebp
0x5578d016b458:  mov    %rbp,0x80(%r14)
0x5578d016b45f:  mov    $0x40008c,%ebp
0x5578d016b464:  mov    %rbp,0x140(%r14)
0x5578d016b46b:  mov    %r14,%rdi
0x5578d016b46e:  mov    $0x2,%esi
0x5578d016b473:  mov    $0x56000000,%edx
0x5578d016b478:  mov    $0x1,%ecx
0x5578d016b47d:  callq  0x5578cfdfe130
0x5578d016b482:  mov    $0x7f8af0565013,%rax
0x5578d016b48c:  jmpq   0x5578d016b416
```

so in the `IN` section, we see our hand written ARM assembly code, and in the `OUT` section we see the generated x86 assembly.

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 amd64, QEMU 2.5.0, binutils 2.26.1.

**QEMU full system emulation**

When you boot Android in QEMU however, it is not running an userland binary of course, but rather doing full system simulation, where it runs the actual Linux kernel and all devices in the simulation.

Full system simulation is more accurate, but a bit slower, and you need to give a kernel and disk image to QEMU.

To try that out, have a look at the following setups:

- build AOSP from source and run it on QEMU: [How to compile the Android AOSP kernel and test it with the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809774/how-to-compile-the-android-aosp-kernel-and-test-it-with-the-android-emulator/48310014#48310014)
- build a minimal beautiful Linux system with Buildroot and run it with QEMU: [How to download the Torvalds Linux Kernel master, (re)compile it, and boot it with QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557262/how-to-download-the-torvalds-linux-kernel-master-recompile-it-and-boot-it-wi/49349237#49349237)
- build and run run baremetal code on QEMU: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/79b35fb395f9f7f7621609186931408fe2f79881#baremetal-setup-getting-started

**KVM**

If you run Android X86 on QEMU, you will notice that it is much faster.

The reason is that QEMU uses [KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine), which is a Linux kernel feature that can run the guest instructions directly on the host!

If you happen to have a powerful ARM machine (yet rare as of 2019), you can also run ARM on ARM with KVM much faster.

For this reason, I recommend that you stick to X86 simulation of AOSP if you are on an X86 host as mentioned at: [How to compile the Android AOSP kernel and test it with the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809774/how-to-compile-the-android-aosp-kernel-and-test-it-with-the-android-emulator/48310014#48310014), unless you really need to touch something low level.

Comment: Exemplary answer. Thanks a lot for all the details & examples.

Answer (score -1):

In [Trend Micro Safe Mobile Workforce](http://www.trendmicro.com/us/enterprise/product-security/safe-mobile-workforce/), we have an ARM runtime (not Intel's houdini) for native library in Android apps. So that we can support running APK with only ARM lib on powerful x86 server.