# Delphi Android app crashes after start

Tags: android, delphi, intel, delphi-10-seattle

I use Delphi 10 Seattle with Mobile Add-On Pack.
My application shows "Application does not support this device" first.
I tried to uncheck the "$(BDS)/lib/android/debug/x86 libnative-activity.so" from the deployment options.
After that the application starts, but crashes after displaying the splash screen.
It happens only on a Samsung Galaxy Tab which contains Intel processor and there is Android 4.4.2 on it.

If I run it on a Bluestacks virtual android device or a tablet which is contains ARM processor, it works.

What should I do to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi Android apps do not support Intel processors. There is nothing you can do.

[Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development)

> The specific requirements are:
>
> - ARM Cortex-A series CPU http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/index.php
> - ARMv7 Instructions
> - NEON Technology
> - GPU

It is possible to run application with libHoudini but it is not officially supported. [Running Delphi Application on Intel Device](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2015-october-running-android-intel.html)

Comment: Houdini should be able to deal with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005303/how-does-native-android-code-written-for-arm-run-on-x86  http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2015-october-running-android-intel.html

Comment: Bluestack virtualize Intel processor and my app works on it after I do this:
https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/blog-menu/entry/running-delphi-applications-on-android-intel

It is not working only this tablet.

Comment: Do you have any kind of ARM virtualization installed on that tablet?

Comment: No, I don't have it. Can I install it somehow?

Comment: Take a look at [libHoudini](http://android-x86.sceners.org/en/?tag=libhoudini) and [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) I haven't used any ARM virtualizations myself so I cannot give you more detailed guide.