# Here Map slow, how to turn off 3d- buildings?

Tags: android, here-api

I'm implementing a simple navigation app with the here-sdk for Android.
It has some great features that would be quite useful compared to my current google maps based app.
However, the app is very slow when navigating as well as when I simply scroll around on the map. I assume that turning off the 3d- buildings would improve the performance, but I cant find a way to achieve this...
Is it possible? And how?

Thanks

Comment: please checkout the 3.2 release scheduled for July as well. There are some performance improvements planned for rendering while navigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Map.setExtrudedBuildingsVisible (boolean visible)

See:
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-map.html#topic-apiref__setextrudedbuildingsvisible-boolean

There's another type of 3D Buildings (3DLandmarks, some 3D Models of famous buildings). Those you can activate/deactivate via setLandmarksVisible(false)

Btw: What device are you running ? What CPU/GPU chipset is it having ? We know that extruded buildings can cause some performance trouble on some few GPUs (see: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/development-tips.html)

Comment: Thanks Marco! That is what I was looking for :) 
I tried it on several devices. I'm sure at least one has a MediaTek GPU. The change improved the performance on most devices Since you seem to know what you're talking about: Do you know whether X86 will be supported someday?

Comment: In general, the ARM HERE SDK can run via emulation/houdini (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005303/how-does-native-android-code-written-for-arm-run-on-x86) and will somehow work (see the HERE Maps app for example), but performance and overall experience is not very good. Right now there are no concrete plans to officially support x86 natively but this doesn't mean that it won't come at all. It's more a business decision than a technical one and mostly depends on the small market share of x86 compared to ARM in the mobile segment.