# Cross compiled go application is running on native machine. How the heck is this possible?

Tags: go

I know go doesn't have multi architecture support in their binary. I am cross compiling a go dbus application and the cross compiled binary is still running on my host computer. I am running debian testing. Can this be a coming up feature or so?

```
$ go version
go version go1.11.5 linux/amd64

$:golang-godbus$ go build

$:golang-godbus$ file golang-godbus 
golang-godbus: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, Go BuildID=rtpT-vZ73aaq-OWCmm29/BqcyUmwm1ybWYgaZEdN7/Ll0SYgA2TzwyWDpTcfmI/fZ-z5lzvDaDWOFC4XHw8, not stripped

$:golang-godbus$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build

$:golang-godbus$ file golang-godbus 
golang-godbus: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=GgidUi9KoU1Ku-VzGDlJ/Lb9Rrl0prlg6BfmlJhvv/Lt1JZ03bbrg1XFqGdA1Q/VNKiL2-y3UnN_7F4P8IP, not stripped
$:golang-godbus$ ./golang-godbus 
Currently owned names on the session bus:
org.freedesktop.DBus
:1.15319
:1.7
org.freedesktop.login1
org.freedesktop.timesync1
:1.10601
:1.10603
org.freedesktop.systemd1
:1.11095
:1.10605
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1
org.freedesktop.Avahi
org.freedesktop.ModemManager1
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager
:1.11
:1.241
org.freedesktop.UDisks2
org.freedesktop.network1
:1.7704
:1.233
fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant
:1.4
fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1
:1.23524
:1.19
:1.6
```

Comment: How does native android code written for ARM run on x86?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13005303/3722896

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go. As you can see from the `file` output, Go has produced the expected binary. Therefor this question may be better suited to Super User than Stack Exchange as it is not actually a question about programming.