# Is there a way to test for whether we are on a breakpoint, using pure gdb scripting?

Tags: c++, gdb

I am attempting to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999457/391161) to generate an instruction trace between two lines of code.

Unfortunately, the condition in the `while` loop is a simple count, and I need to keep running the loop until a particular line of code in the source code is reached.

**Does there exists a way to check whether we are either on a particular line of code, or at a particular breakpoint, within a pure `gdb` script?**

I am aware of the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6964213/391161) which uses the Python API. I am also aware of [pin-instat](https://github.com/wuyongzheng/pin-instat), but I want to know whether this can done with pure gdb.

Comment: What if 1) use `info line ` or use `disas /m` to get information about addresses of the particular line of code and when 2) `while $pc !=  ADDRESS` | `si` | `end` ?. This way you will keep running the loop until a particular line of code in the source code is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if do what you want in this way

1) Get information about `pc` for the line which you would like to reach

Use `info line`  or use `disas /m` to get information about addresses of the particular line of code.

2) Write the similar loop as in [Tracing/profiling instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971926/tracing-profiling-instructions/2999457#2999457)

```
 while $pc != ADDRESS-FROM-FIRST-STEP
   si 
 end.
```

This way you will keep running the loop until a particular line of code in the source code is reached

Comment: With ASLR, which is enabled on most systems, the address will change across runs. By the way, I had meant to respond to the comment but I lost track of it.

Comment: 1) You are running under `gdb`, aren't you? It is possible to disable randomization under gdb with `set disable-randomization`. 2) ASLR on Linux can have three possible values. On my computer its value is 2 and it seems that when I run a program addresses of functions are the same yet addresses of heap are different.